# Have time-release servers been implemented?

Tags: public-key, timed-release

Conceivably, Alice could release a public encryption key and promise to release the private decryption key on a certain date. That way anyone could use that encryption key, combined with others from similar services, and throw away the key so the message will only be readable after a certain proportion of the keys have been released.

This procedure is explained [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RSW96.pdf) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/211.pdf).

Does such a service actually exist to date?